# Confused about handling errors and exceptions in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm just starting to learn RxJava and I've read and watched quite a few tutorials, but some things are not clicking just yet. I've dived in from the deep end and started by modifying one of my app's API calls to return an Observable. Currently the API call is used by an `AsyncTaskLoader` which returns cached data from a local database, then does the call, merges the data and returns it again. This pattern sounded like a perfect subject for my RxJava experiments, but starting small, I want to return an observable from my API call.

This is my original call:

```
public static ArrayList<Stuff> getStuffForId(String id)
        throws IOException, UserNotAuthenticatedException {
    Profile profile = getProfile();
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Stuff>> map = profile.getStuff();
    if (map == null) {
        throw new IOException("error processing - map cannot be null");
    }
    return map.get(id);
}

private static Profile getProfile() 
        throws IOException, UserNotAuthenticatedException {

    // <.. getting url, auth tokens and other stuff to prepare the Request ..>

    Response response = sHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    if (response.code() == ERR_AUTH_REJECTED) {
        throw new UserNotAuthenticatedException(response.body().string());
    }
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String result = response.body().string();
    response.body().close();
    return gson.fromJson(result, Profile.class);
}
```

And in RxJava world I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
public static Observable<ArrayList<Stuff>> getStuffForId(String id) {
    return getProfile().map(
            Profile::getStuff).map(
            map -> {
                if (map == null) {
                    Observable.error(new IOException("error processing - map cannot be null"));
                }
                return map.get(id);
            });
}

private static Observable<Profile> getProfile() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {

        // <.. getting url, auth tokens and other stuff to prepare the Request ..>

        Response response = sHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.code() == ERR_AUTH_REJECTED) {
            throw new UserNotAuthenticatedException(response.body().string(),
                    authToken);
        }
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String result = response.body().string();
        response.body().close();
        return gson.fromJson(result, Profile.class);
    });
}
```

Does this look anything like what one would expect? I'm still not sure of the difference between `fromCallable()` and `defer()` and where you use one or another. Also not sure where do the exceptions go once thrown inside the `fromCallable()` method - will they automagically end up in `onError` of my subscriber or do I need to handle them in my `getStuffForId` method? And finally, Android Studio is warning me that `return map.get(id)` might throw a nullPointer. Is that just because the IDE doesn't understand that `Observable.error` will terminate the execution, or is it that I don't understand what will happen on `Observable.error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) Difference b/w `fromCallable()` and `defer()`?*

Well `defer()` does not create the Observable until some subscriber subscribes and it creates new Obervable each time the user subscribes. Refer this [link](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/) for why you would want to use `defer()`.

*2) Where do exceptions go once thrown inside the `fromCallable()` method?*

Exceptions are caught inside the Observer and then passed as a Throwable object to Subscriber's `onError()` method.

*3) Android Studio is warning me that `return map.get(id)` might throw a nullPointer.*

Its because when it is actually null you are not returning anything in the if statement. The code will run beyond if statement, thus causing nullPointerException. `Observable.error());` returns an Observable and it doesn't throw anything, in order to do that you have to explicitly throw a RuntimeException.

*4) Does this look anything like what one would expect.*

Apart from the above error, there is nothing wrong but you can search online for the rxJava patterns to code better structurally.

Comment: Follow up question - what's more conventional, try/catch block with `Observable.error()` inside catch, or throwing `RuntimeException` with `throw Exceptions.propagate()`. Also, can you recommend any resources for the RxJava patterns? There seems to be quite a few and I'm not sure which ones are best.

Comment: Both are completely different things, `Observable.error()` returns an Observable whereas RuntimeException is well exception. When you use `flatMap()`, that’s when you need `Observable.error()`. For resources there is this [great article](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) on philosophy and use cases of RxJava. And this [nice series](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/) on it.

Comment: thanks. I've actually read danlew's articles already and found them quite useful. will check out the other one you've recommended. Sorry to keep banging about it, but I feel like this part is important to understand. I get that both Obs.err and exceptions are different things, but I still don't understand how to transform the usual throw into RX world. Do I do both in my map function? Send an error with new IOException and throw to terminate? Wrapping all in try/catch for my own throw call seems just wrong..

Comment: Actually rx tries its best to pass down exceptions as onError. If no operator ( onErrorReturn) or subscription handles the exception (onError) you will get an exception thrown at you from the rx world. If you use fromCallable to create a Observable now exception-handling is necessary, because it will wrapp exception with onError. In your example you would use defer, because you could just wrap the exception with Observable.error() and now exception-unwrapping would be neccessary. In your map you need to use flatMap with return Observable.error()

Answer (score 1):

1. Does this look anything like what one would expect

Yes, but please have a look at libraries, which will do the plumbing for you: https://github.com/square/retrofit
If you throw any exception in fromCallable you would use defer and return Observable.error(new Exception("error"))

1. Difference fromCallable / defer

Both methods are factories for creating observables. From callable asks you to return a value as in string etc. Defer like you to return a observable of something. You would use fromCallable if you would like to wrap some non-observable-method-call which returns a certain type. Furthermore fromCallable will handle exceptions for your and pass them down the chain. In contrast you would use defer if you would like to handle your own exception/ observable. You may return a observable which emits a value and then finishes or not finishes. 'fromCallable' will alsways finish with a value(s) and onComplete or onError. With defer you may produce a observable, which will never end as in Observable.never().

2. will they automagically end up in onError

Yes, exception will be caught and passed along as onError. You may handle the error with a operator right away in the chain or you may provide a onError handle (overload) on subscription.

3. return map.get(id) might throw a nullPointer

If you are using RxJava1.x you may encounter null values in the stream, because passing values with onNext(null) are valid. Therefor you would need a null check, due to the possibility of a NPE. Instead of the null-check you could filter-out null values with filter-operator as in:

```
    Observable.just("1", "2", null, "3")
            .filter(s -> s != null)
            .map(s -> s.getBytes())
            .subscribe(bytes -> {
                //...
            });
```

In this case you will get a warning about a possible NPE at s.getBytes(). But due to the filter-operation you can be sure, that s is never null.

Comment: Note that when an exception happens, the "upstream" gets disposed, then `onError()` is triggered.